# To display text in text area

Tags: java, swing

I am making a game which will display a simplification question and user has to solve the question according to BODMAS rule using swings in Java. GUI looks like this [image]

When 'New' button is pressed then new question will be displayed in text area and button label changes to 'Next'
[image]

But if 'Next' button is pressed it does not display next question. operator.txt contains list of simplification question.
the code is as follows

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent buttonEvent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(buttonEvent.getActionCommand().equals("Enter")){
            Double computedVal = EvaluateString(textArea.getText());
            System.out.println(computedVal);
            checkAnswer(computedVal, textField.getText());
        }
        if(buttonEvent.getActionCommand().equals("Clear")){
            ClearTextArea();
        }
        if(buttonEvent.getActionCommand().equals("New")){
            String store = buttonEvent.getActionCommand();
            NewGameOrNext(store);   
        }
    }

private void NewGameOrNext(String store) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(store.equals("New")){
            buttonNew.setText("Next");
        }
        String line = null;
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\operator.txt"));
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                textArea.setText(line);
            }
            reader.close();
        }
        catch(IOException exception){
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

please help me with this!

Comment: try printing out the lines in the console, is the file getting read properly ?

Comment: thanks for replying. I tried it and lines are printing in console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all method names should NOT start with an upper case character. Have you ever seen a method from the Java API start with an upper case character? Some of your method names are correct, others are not. Be consistent!!!

> But if 'Next' button is pressed it does not display next question.

```
if(buttonEvent.getActionCommand().equals("New")){
```

The above conditions will never be true if you reset the text from "New" to "Next".

Seems like you need another if condition to test for "Next". Or, better yet don't change the text, just leave it as "Next".

Comment: hey thanks ! it worked. Actually sometimes I get confused with the naming of methods and class. I will take care of it next time.